# What is the relationship between Melchizedek (Gen. 14) and Adonizedek (Josh. 19)

Tags: ecclesiastes, jerusalem, canaan

Melchizedek is well known as the king of (Jeru-)Salem at the time of Abraham in Gen. 14. Far lesser-known is Adonizedek of Jerusalem, mentioned in Joshua 10:

> Now when Adonizedek, king of Jerusalem, heard that Joshua had captured
> Ai and put it under the ban, and had done to that city and its king as
> he had done to Jericho and its king, and that the inhabitants of
> Gibeon had made their peace with Israel, remaining among them, 2 there
> was great fear abroad...
> 3 So Adonizedek sent this message (to neighboring kings): 4 “Come and help me attack Gibeon, for it
> has made peace with Joshua and the Israelites.”

Both of these kings ruled Jerusalem. Both of them were named "Zedek," meaning righteousness or "the righteous." Both of their names contain an appellation referring to either to their status as ruler (Adoni means lord; Melchi means king) or to their deity.

Does the similarity of these names signify that Adonizedek was a king in Melchizedek's lineage, similar to the "house of David" in the kingdom of Judah? Was it a tradition for the kings of Jerusalem to adopt a throne name ending in "zedek" similar to the "iah" names of Israel and Judah such as Ahaziah, Zedekiah, Pekahiah, Uzziah, etc. What does the bible tell us about any other kings of Jerusalem prior to David? Finally, who was the king of Jerusalem (traditionally believed to be Solomon) referring to when he said:

Ecclesiastes 1:12

> I, Qoheleth, was king over Israel in Jerusalem... I said to myself,
> “See, I have greatly increased my wisdom beyond all who were before me
> in Jerusalem, and my mind has broad experience of wisdom and
> knowledge."

Answer (score 3):

There is no strong evidence of the relationship between Adonizedek and Melchizedek, although both were kings. But both are compound names. Adonizedek means "My Lord is Just" while Mechizedek means "My King is just." The Hebrew word zedek means righteous. There is no evidence that can establish that Adonizedek was of the lineage of Melchizedek.

Comment: Agreed. +1. Nothing is recorded so we do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Since, we know almost nothing about Melchizedek (= "king of righteousness) and Adonizedek (= "Lord of righteousness") other than they were each king of Jerusalem/Salem about 400 years apart, I will only address the last of the OP's questions about the word קֹהֶלֶת Qoheleth.

The word קֹהֶלֶת Qoheleth occurs seven times and only in the book of Ecclesiastes.  This word means "Preacher" or, "Teacher", or more accurately, "collector of wisdom"; see 1 Kings 4:32-34, 2 Chron 9:23.

- Eccl 1:1 - The words of the **Preacher**, the son of David, king in Jerusalem.
- Eccl 1:2 - “Futility of futilities,” says the **Preacher**, “Futility of futilities! All is futility.”
- Eccl 1:12 - I, the **Preacher**, have been king over Israel in Jerusalem.
- Eccl 7:27 - “Behold, I have discovered this,” says the **Preacher**, “by adding one thing to another to find an explanation
- Eccl 12:8 - “Futility of futilities,” says the **Preacher**, “all is futility!”
- Eccl 12:9 - In addition to being wise, the **Preacher** also taught the people knowledge; and he pondered, searched out, and arranged many proverbs.
- Eccl 12:10 - The **Preacher** sought to find delightful words and to write words of truth correctly.

First, note that these instances are arranged with a chiastic pattern. [There are many more such interesting literary patterns in this document which appears to have been composed by a literary master.]

Next, note that the "Preacher" claims to be:

- methodical
- wise
- king in Jerusalem
- Son of David
- king of Israel and in Jerusalem and therefore before Israel was divided during Rehoboam's reign (else he would have only claimed to be king of Judah)
- author of many proverbs

It is obvious why the author is understood to Solomon.  This also accords with long-standing Jewish tradition as well.